# Why doesn't hibernate load persisted entity from second level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, ehcache

Does hibernate put into second level cache entity which I persist with save method?

My code is :

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();

        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Person person = new Person("Volodia", "Levytskyi", "Mykolaiv");
        session.save(person);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();

        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        Person load = (Person) session.load(Person.class, (long) 1);
        System.out.println("load2=" + load);
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
```

I expect hibernate to load from second level cache person but it issues select query to database when

```
session.load(Person.class, (long) 1);
```

is running.

My hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernateSimpleDB</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="format_sql">true</property>
        <property name="transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransactionFactory</property>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>

        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <mapping resource="com/masterhibernate/SimpleHibernateDemo/Person.hbm.xml" 
            />

        <!-- <mapping class="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Person" /> -->
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My Person.hbm.xml :

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.masterhibernate.SimpleHibernateDemo.Person"
        table="Person">
        <cache usage="read-write" />

        <id name="id" column="PersonId">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="name">
            <column name="name" length="16" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="surname">
            <column name="surname" length="36"></column>
        </property>
        <property name="address">
            <column name="address" length="22"></column>
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Why is this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have your database set up to generate primary keys for you. This means that, when you save the entity, it does not yet have an ID, as it will later be assigned by the database. This also means that hibernate cannot store it in the second-level cache, as it doesn't have a key to index it with yet. It should be stored in the second-level cache after retrieving it again from the database though.

Comment: When I use assigned pk generation strategy and assign id explicitly it doesn't go to db and retrieves entity from cache.

Comment: That's what I would have assumed.

Comment: When I do `session.update` of persisted entity, I again have problems that it is not available in second level cache in next created session. Id is set on entity when it is saved, but after update entity  is not available on cache. Why is this?

Comment: Your actual update query might fail, or your database itself might change some values (e.g. by a trigger), etc.